# PHP: How to check if a number has more than two decimals

Tags: php

I'm trying to pick out numbers with more than two decimals (more than two digits after the decimal separator). I cant't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
if ($num * 100 != floor($num * 100)) {
  echo "The number you entered has more than two decimals";
}
```

Why is the number **32.45 picked out, while 32.44 isn't**?

Comment: Decimals are a property of the string representation of numbers, not the numbers themselves

Comment: Will you treat `32.560000` as two-digits number or not?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if 32.560000 is picked out or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
$number = 1.12; //Don't match
$number = 1.123; //Match
$number = 1.1234; //Match
$number = 1.123; //Match

if (preg_match('/\.\d{3,}/', $number)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It still doesn't work with large numbers. But the expression `/.\.\d{3,}/` seems to work fine.

Comment: What do you mean with "It still doesn't work with large numbers" ?

Comment: @user3021737 Please note that `.` in regex means "any character". `\.` means "a literal `.` character". Essentially this answer would match `1234` because it'd be the same as `*[digit][digit][digit]`

Comment: @h2ooooooo you are right, my answer was created with "," and then edited by someone else. I will fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to figure out if it has more than 2 decimals:

```
<?php
    function doesNumberHaveMoreThan2Decimals($number) {
        return (preg_match('/\.[0-9]{2,}[1-9][0-9]*$/', (string)$number) > 0);
    }

    $numbers = array(123.456, 123.450, '123.450', 123.45000001, 123, 123.4);

    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        echo $number . ': ' . (doesNumberHaveMoreThan2Decimals($number) ? 'Y' : 'N') . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
123.456:      Y
123.45:       N
123.450:      N
123.45000001: Y
123:          N
123.4:        N
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/72317)

Regex autopsy (`/\.[0-9]{2,}[1-9][0-9]*$/`):

- `\.` - a literal `.` character
- `[0-9]{2,}` - Digits from 0 to 9 matched 2 or more times
- `[1-9]` - A digit between 1 and 9 matched a single time (to make sure we ignore trailing zeroes)
- `[0-9]*` - A digit between 0 and 9 matched 0 to infinity times (to make sure that we allow `123.4510` even though it ends with `0`).
- `$` - The string MUST end here - nothing else can be between our last match and the end of the string

Comment: Fail with trailing zeros at least.

Comment: @AlmaDo You're right - that's fixed now, even though trailing zeroes would never be existing in a floating type.

Comment: I _may be_ right. OP didn't mentioned that - so I was just noticing

Comment: Yet another fail: `var_dump(doesNumberHaveMoreThan2Decimals('foo34.6654')); //true`

Comment: @AlmaDo Sure - but OP was doing calculations with it, so you'd expect it to be either a float or something that could be casted as a float. `(float)'foo34.6654')` outputs `0` so it can't be casted. Within OPs scope there's no reason to do this. Surely `(string)$number` could easily be switched out with `(string)(float)$number` but why bother to double cast it?

Answer (score 1):

I know, its an old question, but why not just do:

```
function onlyDecimals($number, $maxDecimalPlaces = 2) {
   return $amount == number_format($amount, $maxDecimalPlaces, ".", "");
}
```

See example and tests: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e68143a9ed0b6dfcad9ab294c44fa7e802c39dd0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function (works with negative numbers, too):

```
function decimalCheck($num) {
    $decimals = ( (int) $num != $num ) ? (strlen($num) - strpos($num, '.')) - 1 : 0;
    return $decimals >= 2;
}
```

Test cases:

```
$numbers = array(
    32.45,
    32.44,
    123.21,
    21.5454,
    1.545400,
    2.201054,
    0.05445,
    32,
    12.0545400,
    12.64564,
    -454.44,
    -0.5454
);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number. "\t : \t";
    echo (decimalCheck($number)) ? 'true' : 'false';
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
32.45    :  true
32.44    :  true
123.21   :  true
21.5454  :  true
1.5454   :  true
2.201054 :  true
0.05445  :  true
32       :  false
12.05454 :  true
12.64564 :  true
-454.44  :  true
-0.5454  :  true
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/72327)